# An 'infinitely conditioned' state in a C*-algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

**Edit: I have worked on the problem a bit, and thus have refocussed. The first part has now been [asked at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450349/conditioning-a-mathrmc-algebra-state-with-infinite-precision).**

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a unital $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra. Let $f\in \mathcal{A}$ self-adjoint with spectrum $\sigma(f)$. The bidual $\mathcal{A}^{**}$ contains the spectral projections of $f$, denoted $\mathbf{1}_{E}(f)$, for Borel $E\subseteq \sigma(f)$. Let $\lambda\in\sigma(f)$, $\varepsilon>0$ and define
$$p_\varepsilon(f):=\mathbf{1}_{(\lambda-\varepsilon,\lambda+\varepsilon)}(f).$$

Suppose that $\varphi$ is a state on $\mathcal{A}$, with an extension to a state on $\mathcal{A}^{**}$ denoted $\omega_\varphi$. Suppose further, and this is to be a key assumption, that for all $\varepsilon>0$, $$\omega_\varphi(p_\varepsilon(f))>0\qquad(\star).$$

If the following is defined, it defines a state. But is it well-defined?

**Question: Let $g\in\mathcal{A}$. Under the assumption $(\star)$, does the following limit exist:**

$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\frac{\omega_\varphi(p_\varepsilon(f)\,g\,p_\varepsilon(f))}{\omega_\varphi(p_\varepsilon(f))}.$$

If this is well-defined, it defines a state $\varphi_\lambda$ on $\mathcal{A}$ with extension to the bidual $\omega_\lambda$. I want to show that:
$$\omega_\lambda(\mathbf{1}_{\{\lambda\}}(f))=1.$$
In a naive way, if the $\varphi_\lambda$ is well-defined, this seems easy. Roughly:
$$\varphi_\lambda(\mathbf{1}_{\{\lambda\}}(f))=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\frac{\omega_\varphi(\mathbf{1}_{\{\lambda\}}(f))}{\omega_\varphi(p_\varepsilon(f))},$$
and then what can be helpful is that facts about Borel functional calculus, and the $\sigma$-weak continuity of $\omega_\lambda$, shows that:
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\omega_\varphi(p_\varepsilon(f))=\omega_\varphi(\mathbf{1}_{\{\lambda\}}(f)).$$
But the problem here is that $\varphi_\lambda$ is a state on $\mathcal{A}$ and that spectral projection is in the bidual. So the natural thing would be to take $(\phi_\alpha)\subset \mathcal{A}$ converging $\sigma$-weakly to $\mathbf{1}_{\{\lambda\}}(f)$, and then write down something like:
$$\omega_\lambda(\mathbf{1}_{\{\lambda\}}(f))=\lim_\alpha\left[\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\frac{\omega_\varphi(p_{\varepsilon}(f)\phi_\alpha p_{\varepsilon}(f))}{\omega_\varphi(p_\varepsilon (f))}\right]$$
If I can exchange these limits, I can use $\sigma$-continuity, and spectral projection stuff to get back to the naive picture:
$$\omega_\lambda(\mathbf{1}_{\{\lambda\}}(f)))=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\frac{\omega_\varphi(\mathbf{1}_{\{\lambda\}}(f))}{\omega_\varphi(p_\varepsilon(f))}$$

**Question: Can these limits be exchanged?**

Comment: Is $1_{\{\lambda\}}(f)$ not zero since the singleton has measure zero?

Comment: @PStheman Let $\mathcal{A}=C([0,1])$ and $f$ given by $f(t)=t$. Isn't $\mathbf{1}_{\{1/2\}}(f)$ something like a Kronecker delta function? The bidual is not $\ell^{\infty}([0,1])$ but I understand it contains stuff like that. Another POV is that $f$ generates the algebra. $g\to g(1/2)$ is a state on it. What is its support projection but that apectral projection?

Comment: ahh I think I jumped the gun, my bad.

Comment: A counterexample [has been given by Nik Weaver](https://mathoverflow.net/a/450365/35482) over on MO.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer, a CW link to an MO question, is not being accepted as an answer, and has been converted to a comment.